# salvar em arquivo um retorno da backend

Tags: javascript, html, arquivo, xls, binary

minha controller do backend retorna um arquivo do tipo xlsx para meu front, esse é o metodo que faz o retorno:

```
 public FileResult ListarLivrosExcel()
    {
        // Gerando minha planilha e recebendo-a
        using (ExcelPackage arquivoExcel = new BmpoDTO().Gerar())
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            arquivoExcel.SaveAs(stream);

            // Mais sobre contentType:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166205/mime-type-for-excel-xml-asp-net-3-5
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            string fileName = "Livros.xlsx";

            stream.Position = 0;
            return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
        }
    }
```

bom, o que eu esperava era que o browser fizesse o download do arquivo no formato xlsx, porem nao ocorre o download automaticamente.

debugando eu consigo ver os binarios do retorno :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é possivel usar JS para salvar esses binarios ?
ou teria como forçar um download pelo browser no formato xlsx?

resultado usandoo blob
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Na função que você está chamando (ex: callback de uma requisição ajax), você pode criar um arquivo a partir de [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob), associar o endereço a um *link* e efetuar o download, algo mais ou menos como:

```
function download(data){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    // data são os bytes do arquivo
    // createObjectURL cria um novo objeto URL para permitir o download
    var blob =  new Blob(["\ufeff", data], {
                type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
        , url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "meu_arquivo.xlsx";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

> Um Blob object representa um objeto, do tipo arquivo, com  dados
>   brutos imutáveis. Blobs representam dados que não estão
>   necessáriamente em formatos padrões do JavaScript. A interface File é
>   baseada no Bloob, herdando blob funcionalmente e expandindo ele para
>   dar suporte aos arquivos do sistema do usuário.

Referência de [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURl).

Comment: salvou, porem ao abrir o arquivo, mostra os binarios, editei o poste e coloquei uma foto.